How to fix data not show in page but appear in network preview
im trying to post image that been convert to url by using ajax. The problem is $image = $_POST['imgData']; not show anything but if i check developer tools on network preview the data can be seen.
this is my script
        var canvas = document.getElementById('chart1');
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1);
        //console.log(imgData);


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "?f=view_customer_list",
            data: { imgData: imgData },
            success: function(response) {
                alert(imgData);
            }
        });

php code
  $image = $_POST['imgData'];
  
  echo $image;

i want the url can be echo in my page

Please note that the HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL() method returns a data URL containing a representation of the image in the format specified by the type parameter. For further details, you may refer to documentation in mozilla
Referring to the code you posted - you have a number of things need to note and/or fix:

a normal JS alert, such as alert(imgData) will not be able to display any image/graphic
the PHP you are trying to use has echo $image; as the last line, but this will not be able to display an image by itself, you should use echo "<img src='". $image . "'>"; instead (if you want to display an image in a standalone way)
imgData will not be able to return anything from the PHP thru ajax, you should use response instead since you are using success: function(response) { ... }

So to demonstrate how you can pass the canvas data to PHP thru ajax and then return, you can use the following
HTML
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id=ajaxreturn></div>

<canvas id="chart1" width="200" height="100" >

<script>
   var c = document.getElementById("chart1");
   var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(95, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
   ctx.stroke();
</script>



<script>
   var canvas = document.getElementById('chart1');
   var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1);
     //console.log(imgData);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "testajax.php",
            data: { imgData: imgData },
            success: function(response) {
               document.getElementById('ajaxreturn').innerHTML=response;
            }
        });

</script>

PHP (testajax.php)
<?php
$image = $_POST['imgData'];
echo "<img src='". $image . "'>"; 
?>

Note:

I added code to draw a circle in the canvas, so that something can be passed to the PHP by ajax (but of course you can use other methods to draw something in the canvas)
The return of ajax will be an image display statement in the form of "<img src='". $image . "'>". Since an alert will not be display such an image, I have added a DIV with id "ajaxreturn" to the HTML so that the system can place the returned image in this DIV

The result (I captured my own browser screen dump) will be :

The lower circle is the one which we have drawn in canvas, and the upper circle is the image returned from PHP thru ajax

i try to alert imgdata just to check and what im trying to do is echo the url itself not the image. I know how to use the url with img tag. my problem is on my page $_POST['imgData'] did not show anything but i can see the url in network preview

(1) study what HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL() means first (otherwise I will not put it as the 1st paragraph in my answer) (2) please read all my answer and you know what is/are the things to fix in your code - (a) alert (b) what is returned in ajax, etc.
